# How to add the column to list view in openerp?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am new to openerp. [image: List view image]I need to add the column to list view. Please see the dark line in the attached image.

Is any possibility to add extra column to listview using xml. for example hr_view.xml.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, you need to inherit the tree view like,

```
   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_tree_view">
        <field name="name">hr.tree.form.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="name" position='after'>
                <field name="Your_field"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Try this, it will work.